# Magento API call for getting products information

Tags: php, api, soap, magento

I used the below code to get products details from a magento store from my localhost

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain.com/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');

$sessionId = $proxy->login('username', 'apikey');
$filters = array(
    'sku' => array('like'=>'test%')
);

$products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', array($filters));

var_dump($products);
```

It works on my localhost machine but not on server. But soap configuration is enabled in server. Below is the error message

" **SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find <definitions> in** "

I got corresponding xml file when I used the below URL
http://domainname/shoponline/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl

I removed index.php but didn't get any result.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain.com/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
```

The above statement display the below error

```
Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find definitions in
```

Comment: Try going to the WSDL url with your browser.  What do you get?  Maybe try removing the index.php from it.

Comment: got corresponding xml file when i used the below url http://domainname/shoponline/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl

I removed index.php .but didn't get any result. $proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain.com/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl'); The above statement display the below error Parsing WSDL: " SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find <definitions> in "

Comment: The code you posted goes to a different url than what you just tested.  Does your code use the url containing "shoponline", or "magento"?

Comment: it is magento. it is an example

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the WSDL XML file was not loaded at all. To debug, try to open this file in your browser.
I guess it will not be loaded at all and you'll get an error (which will help you to find out what's wrong) or you will be asked to input username and password (basic HTTP auth). In the second case try change your URL from `http://domain.com/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl` to `http://user:pass@domain.com/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you disable developer mode and error reporting in index.php.

Comment: thanks, I was scratching my head for a while, this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "hosts" file from `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc` and comment out the line `::1` (like this: `# ::1`) or remove the line altogether, then save the file.

I've also used this service - http://localhost:81/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The SoapClient unable to retrive wsdl definition file which means that routing is not configured correctly or there some external error occurs. But most likely it's a routing problem. The api/[type] rewrite rule is commented in .htaccess, so you need to remove # sign or use api.php directly. To make api.php work directly you need to pass type parameter to api.php to specify which API protocol you would like to use.

For example, for SOAP it will be - http://domain.com/magento/api.php?type=soap&wsdl. You can also use 'soap_v2'.